# How to send Asp.Net form data after a while?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm creating a quiz website using ASP.Net Core 3.1. I have a simple form containing several inputs (questions). My purpose is to set a timer which posts the data of the form after a period (for example 10 minutes) even if user not clicked the submit button.

**Edit:**
This is my form:

```
<form method="post">
<p>Explain the picture (You have 10 minutes):</p>
<input asp-for="Answer" class="form-control" />
<input type="submit" value="Send Answers">
</form>
```

Is there anyway that form be posted after 10 minutes automatically?

Comment: `setTimeout` is your friend.

Comment: @DanielA.White Would you explain it more please? I'm noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to create desired behaviour

```
<form id="myForm" action="index" method="post"></form>

<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
        this.document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    }, 10 * 60 * 1000) // 10 minutes * 60 seconds * 1000 ms
</script>
```

Comment: I guess it's exactly what I was searching for, but is this safe? I mean can a user disable it?

Comment: Sure, he can. If he disables javascript execution on a page, form will never be submitted. there is nothing you could do about that, unfortunately. but i don't think you should keep such rare case in mind

Comment: Alright! Thanks again